# Which ML method should I use to make a prediction function for accident data?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear, learning

I have road accident data from 2000 to 2020 with counts divided into categories like "Junction Type" etc.?
I want to build a prediction model using ML, So which technique should I use Linear regression, Logistic regr...etc[image: Accident Data]